# .data() returns string when table needed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jinja2

In my html I've got a table:
`<table id="table" data-keys="{{keys}}">`
where `keys` are an array (I later succesfully call
`{% for k in keys %}`).

But when in my js I call:
`$("#table").data("keys")` the result is string:
`"['', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']"`
Is there anything smart that I can do to actually get the table or do I simply need to parse the string and convert it by myself?

Comment: HTML attributes don't store arrays or objects, only strings

Comment: So the answer is: no, there is nothing else you can do. Thank you :)

Comment: @JeremyThille that's correct for `$(..).attr("data-item")` -> always a string.  *However* `$(..).data("item")` *will* attempt to coerce the attribute string to the correct data type (eg number).  (so yes, they're *stored* as strings, so "where keys is an array" is incorrect as it's a string)

Comment: @freedomn-m ah, that is very possible. My jQuery is a bit rusty

Comment: @JeremyThille updated my comment - you are correct in that they only store strings

Comment: @Malvinka No, I didn't say that

Answer (score 3):

You have to use double quotes for the string to be valid JSON. It will then be automatically parsed by jQuery.

```js
const a = $('#a').data("keys");
const b = $('#b').data("keys");

console.log(typeof a, a)
console.log(typeof b, b)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="a" data-keys='["", "a", "b", "c"]'></div>
<div id="b" data-keys="['', 'a', 'b', 'c']"></div>
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/

> Every attempt is made to convert the attribute's string value to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null)
> [...]
> **When a string starts with '{' or '[', then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse it; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names. A string not parseable as a JavaScript value is not converted.**